# Integrating a transformed density without being able to do change-of-variable?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I'm trying to calculate
$$
\int \frac{\rho(x)}{\rho(f(x))} \nu(f(x)) dx,
$$
where $\rho,\nu$ are regular probability densities (or corresponding marginal densities), $f$ is non-invertible, and cannot be extended as such (while matching the dimension of $x$). How can I proceed?

Comment: What kind of answer are you hoping for?  Surely you don't expect a closed-form solution in this generality.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Could you give an example of this integral not equaling 1?

Comment: Try $f(x) = x^2$ on $[-1, 1]$ (to make it non-invertible), $\rho = 1/2$, $\nu(x) = (x+1)/2$.